# Run Code Once per Button Press - Arduino

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, arduino

I am stuck trying to get certain pieces of code code to run only once per button press (digitalRead).

```
void setup() {
    // Set up and init all outputs to off
    pinMode(2, INPUT);
    pinMode(7, INPUT);

    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);
    Serial.println("Test");

    for(byte i = 0; i<OutputCount; i++){
        pinMode( outputs[i][OutputPin], OUTPUT);
        digitalWrite( outputs[i][OutputPin], LOW );

        // Set up an event fuse for this output.
        eventFuse.newFuse( i, outputs[i][OffTime], INF_REPEAT, OutputHandler );
    }

    // Set MsTimer2 for one second per tick.
    MsTimer2::set(100, timerTick );
    MsTimer2::start();
}

void loop(){
    if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
        while (i < 1){
            switchPos = 2;
            MsTimer2::start();
            i++;
        }
    }
    else if (digitalRead(7) == HIGH) {
        while (i < 1){
            switchPos = 7;
            MsTimer2::stop();
        }
    }
    else {
        switchPos = 0;
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

The above code uses the box-standard Lamp Timer example that comes with the MsTimer2 and EventFuse libraries.

In the loop section there are some while loops which seam to be infinite loops. All I need is a war to run the code you see inside the while loops only once. Any ideas?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your loops? You have one single-iteration loop (i.e. serves no additional purpose), and one always infinite loop. Also, where do you define i?

Comment: You may have forgotten `i++` in the second `while` in `loop()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple implementation using some flags:

```
int twoFlag, sevenFlag;

void loop(){
    if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
        if (!twoFlag) {
            switchPos = 2;
            MsTimer2::start();
            delay(10); // to avoid errors from chattering or bouncing
            twoFlag = 1;
        }
    } else {
        twoFlag = 0;
    }
    if (digitalRead(7) == HIGH) {
        if (!sevenFlag) {
            switchPos = 7;
            MsTimer2::stop();
            delay(10); // to avoid errors from chattering or bouncing
            sevenFlag = 1;
        }
    } else {
        sevenFlag = 0;
    }
}
```